# Hover div, change :after pseudo of another div

Tags: jquery, html, css, pseudo-element

Is it possible to change a div's pseudo-element `:after` when hovering over over another div? It would look something like this:

```css
.div2:after {
  width: 34px;
  height: 2px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  content: "";
  background-color: red;
  background-clip: content-box;
}
.div:hover + .div2:after {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">hover here</div>
<div class="div2">...</div>
```

I know I could add styles with Js, but a CSS only solution would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector was fine, you just need to define the content:

```css
.div:hover + .div2:after {
  content: 'hovering!'
}
```

```html
<div class="div">...</div>
<div class="div2">...</div>
```

Or an example with content both hovering and non-hovering:

```css
.div2:after {
  content: 'not hovering'
}
.div:hover + .div2:after {
  content: 'hovering!'
}
```

```html
<div class="div">...</div>
<div class="div2">...</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to first define the `:after` pseudo element and give it some content, then you can use the selector you defined to amend the properties on that pseudo element. Try this:

```css
.div2:after {
  content: 'FOO';
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.div:hover + .div2:after {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">Hover me!</div>
<div class="div2">My :after content changes colour!</div>
```

You can amend the `:hover` state CSS to change whatever properties you require.